# Convert CassandraRDD to RDD[Array[String]]

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark-mllib, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I have Cassandra Table and I have selected some columns to do Association rules on them. I have created case class for each column to save them in it.
I have the column data of type

**com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraRDD[SuperStoreSalesRG]**

where SuperStoreSalesRG is the case class for single column
I want to convert it to

**RDD[Array[String]]**

How to Do that ?!

many thanks..

this is what I've tried so far

```
val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("demo1", "orders4") 

case class SuperStoreSalesPC (ProductCategory: String) 
case class SuperStoreSalesCS (CustomerSegment: String) 
case class SuperStoreSalesRG (Region: String) 

val resultPC = test_spark_rdd.select("productcategory").as(SuperStoreSalesP‌​C) 
val resultCS = test_spark_rdd.select("customersegment").as(SuperStoreSalesC‌​S) 
val resultRG = test_spark_rdd.select("region").as(SuperStoreSalesRG)
```

I want to convert each of vals: resultPC, resultCS, resultRG in separate RDD[Array[String]] where these vals are the columns

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far? at least share the dataframe you've already read from cassandra and which column you want to convert?

Comment: val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable("demo1", "orders4")                                                               case class SuperStoreSalesPC (ProductCategory: String)
case class SuperStoreSalesCS (CustomerSegment: String)
case class SuperStoreSalesRG (Region: String)                                                                       val resultPC = test_spark_rdd.select("productcategory").as(SuperStoreSalesPC)
val resultCS = test_spark_rdd.select("customersegment").as(SuperStoreSalesCS)
val resultRG = test_spark_rdd.select("region").as(SuperStoreSalesRG)

Comment: I want to convert each of vals: resultPC, resultCS, resultRG  in separate RDD[Array[String]] where these vals are the columns                                                           @RameshMaharjan

Comment: because I want to use this data for the Association rules example                                   https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html

Answer (score 0):

After you separate the three columns `"productcategory", "customersegment", "region"` into three datasets `resultPC, resultCS, resultRG`, you can do the following to convert each of the `datasets` to `RDD[Array[String]]`

**First step** would be to use inbuilt `collect_list` function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val arrayedResultPC = resultPC.withColumn("productcategory", collect_list("productcategory"))
```

which would create `datasets` with following `schema`

```
root
 |-- productcategory: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

You can do the same for other two datasets

**Final step** would be to convert the collected `datasets` to `RDD[Array[String]]`

```
val arrayedRdd = arrayedResultPC.rdd.map(_.toSeq(0).asInstanceOf[mutable.WrappedArray[String]])
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: When I applied this step                                                                              
val arrayedResultPC = resultPC.withColumn("productcategory", collect_list("productcategory"))                                                                                 this error apears to me:                                                                                               <console>:51: error: value withColumn is not a member of test_spark_rdd.Self
       val arrayedResultPC = resultPC.withColumn("productcategory", collect_list("productcategory"))

Comment: withColumn should work with dataframes and datasets. Make sure that you are applying the api on dataframe object.